# Python - how to remove nested key

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, nested-lists

```
a={
"car": "Nissan",
"from": [
    {
        "Japan1": "People1",
        "make_type": "allow",
        "driver": {
            "id": "12345",
            "name": "user1",
            "type": "user"
        }
    },
    {
        "Japan1": "People1",
        "make_type": "allow",
        "driver": {
            "id": "98765",
            "name": "user2",
            "type": "user"
        }
    }
]}
```

Objective: want to remove "name" and "type" inside "driver"

I have tried a lot of  method, if use print the name or type,  just put into a new var level by level.

But how can I delete it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `del`:

```py
for f in a["from"]:
    del f["driver"]["name"]
    del f["driver"]["type"]

print(a)
```

Prints:

```py
{
    "car": "Nissan",
    "from": [
        {"Japan1": "Peop1", "make_type": "plastic", "driver": {"id": "12345"}}
    ],
}
```

---

Or:

```py
for f in a["from"]:
    f["driver"] = {
        k: v for k, v in f["driver"].items() if k not in {"name", "type"}
    }
```

Comment: oh sorry, actually the driver can have more than 1 driver, let me edit the question

Comment: @VincentLam The code in the answer will work for multiple driver in your dictionary.